# Decrementing multiple numbers with the same class on a single page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I have 6 numbers on a page, each inside of it's own div with a class of 'interval'. I need to decrement the innerHTML of EACH of the integers inside of the DIV with a singular javascript method.. Here's the html:

```
<div class="timer">54</div>
<div class="timer">98</div>
<div class="timer">100</div>
<div class="timer">24</div>
<div class="timer">8</div>
<div class="timer">16</div>
```

Here's my attempted JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var intervalCountDown = window.setInterval(decrementTimeRemaining, 1000);

    function decrementTimeRemaining() {
       $('.timer').html($(".timer").html() - 1);
    }

});
```

The expected output (after 1 second) would be 53, 97, 99, 23, 7, 15. Each second these numbers would decrement again.. Instead what's happening is that after the first second, EVERY element with the timer class becomes 53, and then they're all concurrent decrement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.html(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function):

```
$('.timer').html(function(index, html) {
  return html - 1;
});
```

In your case you can also use [`.text(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function):

```
$('.timer').text(function(index, text) {
  return text - 1;
});
```

Note that each value is a string `"54"`, `"98"`, ... and will therefore need to be casted to numbers, this happens automatic when using the unary minus (`-`) operator, but wont happen if you use the unary plus (`+`) operator, because it's also the concatenation operator:

```
"2" - 1 // 1
"2" + 1 // "21"
```

Take a look at [`parseInt(string, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: I am unable to get this to work, and I'm not sure why, I will look more closely into the .html(function)

Comment: I see this, and it looks cleaner, but how do I imlement the var intervalCountDown = window.setInterval(decrementTimeRemaining, 1000); into this, so it happens every second? I knew the concatenation would be a problem and should do a parseInt as others have suggested below, just not sure how to get this to happen every second with your method.

Comment: @Kulingar Np mate, jQuery is cool in that way, usually have a function you can send in and it will automatic iterate over each element for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
function decrementTimeRemaining() {
   $('.timer').each(function(idx, value) {
       $(value).html(parseInt($(value).html()) - 1);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys, it's really the "each" that makes this work.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have not picked all elements which have class name as "timer". You have to use `each` method from jquery to loop through all the elements and then use `$(this)` to pick and update current field in loop.
Use following code snippet.

```
    <script>
        window.setInterval(decrementTimeRemaining, 1000);
        function decrementTimeRemaining() {
            $('.timer').each(function(){            
            $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html()) - 1);
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys, it's really the "each" that makes this work